# Выборка из базы mySQL и замена

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть две таблицы t1 и t2, в таблицах есть аналогичные столбцы text, attribute и id. id повторяются и отличаются только по attribute. в таблице t2 столбец text заполнен, а в таблице t1 столбец text пустой и его надо заполнить как в t2.

Пример:

```
t1
id_____attribute_____text
1.........11..........
1.........12..........
2.........11..........
2.........12..........

t2
id_____attribute_____text
1.........11.........abc
1.........12.........efg
2.........11.........igk
2.........12.........xyz
```

Пишу вот такую конструкцию:

> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET text = REPLACE (text,t1.text) WHERE
> t1.id = t2.id AND t1.attribute=t2.attribute
> ```

Выпадает ошибка - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1

Второй день бьюсь, помогите!

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON
    t1.id = t2.id AND t1.attribute = t2.attribute
SET t1.text = t2.text;
```

Больше по даному вопросу можно найти здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql

Comment: Да, этот вариант тот что нужно! Спасибо огромное!